# Convert MacOS-style path to POSIX path in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, unix, posix

I'm on OSX and would like to convert a MacOS-style path (e.g. Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:) to a POSIX-path (e.g. /Users/Shared/).

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a legacy Mac path to a POSIX path using AppleScript, which you can call from the shell using `osascript`:

```
$ osascript -e 'POSIX path of "Macintosh HD:Users:Shared"'
/Users/Shared
```

Comment: Works flawless. Edited post and title.

Comment: @Hedge Glad to hear it! I've edited the correction out of my answer since you've edited your post.